# Spring Security Oauth + Firebase

Tags: spring, rest, restful, spring-security, firebase

Boa tarde.

Estou implementando a camada de segurança da minha aplicação.
Decidi que vamos utilizar o Firebase para realizar a autenticação, e quando o mesmo retornar o token de acesso para o cliente ele enviará esse token para o meu servidor Java que vai verificar no Firebase se o token é válido e ai retornar um token da minha aplicação para o Cliente.

A minha dificuldade é na implementação no meu servidor Java. Como eu recebo esse token(sei fazer com usuário e senha, por exemplo, mas não recebendo o token) no Spring Security Oauth, faço a verificação no Firebase(já sei a implementação dessa verificação) e se correr tudo bem retorno o token pro cliente?

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seja legal você usar o [Firebase Queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) pra executar esse tipo de tarefa complexa. Tava escrevendo sobre ele hoje mesmo pro meu time. Se liga só:

O Firebase Queue é um módulo do Firebase que nos permite criar quatro elementos que solucionam o escalonamento da nossa plataforma de uma maneira que os desenvolvedores do Plone não poderiam imaginar nem em seus sonhos mais molhados. Uma “Queue”, ou fila, é um lugar no banco de dados em que você joga tarefas para serem completadas. O ciclo de vida de cada Queue é fundamentado em quatro conceitos principais: task, worker, spec e job.

Cada “task” é uma tarefa representada como um objeto no banco de dados e ela pode ser processada por um worker.

“Workers”, ou trabalhadores, são processos que ficam esperando por tasks que são adicionadas no banco de dados. A cada tarefa adicionada, os workers observam o spec da task e decidem se vão ou não tentar processá-la. O primeiro worker que começar a trabalhar rouba a task para si e nenhum outro worker pode interferir nela até que ele a tarefa esteja completa ou retorne um erro.

O “spec” é uma definição das coisas que a task faz em relação a outras tasks. Você pode definir ligações entre as tasks como “quando completar a task X, inicie a task Y” ou “inicie a task X com estes parâmetros aqui”.

“Job” é um conjunto de specs que definem uma série de operações a serem executadas em ordem.

Para saber como implementar tudo isso, é só ler o guia oficial em https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue/blob/master/docs/guide.md